# Issue while compilng java code from django

Tags: java, python, django, subprocess

I am new to django web development currently i am trying to create online java compiler using django  which consists of two fields i.e code(we can write our own logic) and inputfield(we can provide our  own input field) in this process i am facing issue while executing java program
with below code
here is my code
and i am using python 2.7 and django 1.8

```
   import re
   import os
   from django.shortcuts import render
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from .forms import GetForm

  import subprocess
  def index(request):
      if request.method=="GET":
          form=GetForm()
          return render(request,'compile.html',{'form':form})
      else:
          form =GetForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
                main_class_name=""
                text=form.cleaned_data["code"] 
              // here main_class_name holds main class java name
                for i in re.split('class ',text)[1:]:
                         if re.search('public static void main',i):
                               main_class_name=re.search('(\w*)',i).group(1)
               os.chdir('/home/username/Desktop/onlineproject/projectCompiler/javacompile/')
               sd=open(main_class_name+".java","a")
               sd.write(text)
               proc = 
               subprocess.Popen(['javac',main_class_name+'.java'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
               cmd=['java', main_class_name]
               output =subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True,
               stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
               form.save()
       return render(request,'compile.html',{'form1':text})
```

#My issue

My issue is i am able to compile and generate the .class file using above python script but i am unable to run the java code using "java classname" using above python script
and also i am not getting any error while executing the above code

please help me

Comment: You open the file and write to the file but you never close the file. Also you open the file in append mode, what happens if main class name is the same for multiple executions? You just add to some previous code.

Comment: I have tried but not getting the wanted output